# Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.22

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I am trying to spin up my old L4 site on Digital Ocean. After cloning everything, I tried running :

**sudo composer update**

```
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)                      
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.22
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.21
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.20
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.19
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.18
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.17
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.16
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.15
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.14
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.13
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.12
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.11
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.3
    - Installation request for zizaco/entrust dev-master -> satisfiable by zizaco/entrust[dev-master].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.1
    - zizaco/entrust dev-master requires illuminate/cache ~5.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/cache[v5.0.0, v5.0.22, v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.28, v5.0.33, v5.0.4, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8, v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.9].
    - don't install illuminate/cache v5.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/cache v5.0.22|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/cache v5.0.25|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/cache v5.0.26|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/cache v5.0.28|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/cache v5.0.33|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/cache v5.0.4|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/cache v5.1.1|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/cache v5.1.13|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/cache v5.1.16|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/cache v5.1.2|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/cache v5.1.20|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/cache v5.1.22|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/cache v5.1.25|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/cache v5.1.28|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/cache v5.1.30|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/cache v5.1.31|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/cache v5.1.41|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/cache v5.1.6|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/cache v5.1.8|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/cache v5.2.0|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/cache v5.2.19|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/cache v5.2.21|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/cache v5.2.24|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/cache v5.2.25|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/cache v5.2.26|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/cache v5.2.27|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/cache v5.2.28|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/cache v5.2.31|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/cache v5.2.32|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/cache v5.2.37|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/cache v5.2.43|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/cache v5.2.45|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/cache v5.2.6|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/cache v5.2.7|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/cache v5.3.0|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/cache v5.3.16|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/cache v5.3.23|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/cache v5.3.4|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/cache v5.4.0|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/cache v5.4.13|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/cache v5.4.9|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 4.2.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v4.2.0, v4.2.1, v4.2.10, v4.2.11, v4.2.12, v4.2.13, v4.2.14, v4.2.15, v4.2.16, v4.2.17, v4.2.18, v4.2.19, v4.2.2, v4.2.20, v4.2.21, v4.2.22, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9].
```

**How do I stop this ?**

Comment: try composer install instead of update

Comment: Both give me same results.

Comment: There is a package in your package.json that requires a lower/higher version of Laravel. If you could show your package.json or simply remove packages to see which one is the cause.

Comment: try removing 'zizaco' from your application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The master branch of the `zizaco/entrust` package requires Laravel 5. The last tagged version of the `zizaco/entrust` package that supports Laravel 4 is `1.3.0`. You need to update your `composer.json` file to require `"zizaco/entrust": "1.3.*"`, instead of dev-master.