# upgrade laravel 4.1 to 5 step by step

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4, laravel-5.3

I am trying to upgrade my laravel 4.1.30 project to laravel 5. But I searched instructions online many times, even official described not clearly.Please lead me to be able to upgrade step by step.

Comment: What about this?  https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#upgrade-5.0

Comment: more precisely https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#upgrade-4.2

Comment: my laravel version is just 4.1.30

Comment: when I run composer update  it show me

Comment: Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.22
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.21

Comment: There is no detail upgrate guide found in official site, please

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can I'm also in a process of doing upgrade with a project from 4.0 to 5.

Currently I have upgraded from 4.0 to 4.2 and now gonna upgrade it to 5 as well.

What I figured out is that you have to follow all upgrade process step by step as described in the guide.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade

It means, you have to do all small upgrades as well for example, "Upgrading To 4.1.29 From <= 4.1.x" also needs to be done.

I hope it helps.

Comment: When I run composer update I got the error message
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.22
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.21

Comment: Do not use composer update, remove your vender folder and run composer install after updating your composer.json file

Comment: Thanks, I will try it.

Comment: After deleting the vendor dir and run composer install finished, php artisan show me still 4.1.30.

Comment: Can you please share your ascendancies section of your composer.json file.

Comment: please give me email. the comment avoid me to load the file it said too long.

Comment: I have sent my composer.json file to you, thank you very much for helping me

Comment: In your composer.json you have selected         "laravel/framework": "4.1.*", rather than doing this use exact version line I gave in example and as given in documentation, this way you are always getting 4.1.30 as latest version for 4.1 was 4.1.30, after that I think it was laravel 4.2

Comment: Change your composer.json to         "laravel/framework": "4.2.*" and try now.

Comment: after changing here with 4.2 it also reinstall with 4.1.30 I think it do jobs with composer.lock. but when I run with composer update and then it  show me with error message below.

Comment: Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages. Problem 1 - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.22 - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.21

Comment: Can you please check if there is any package which doesn't support 4.2 at all. 

Here I found a reference and I think might be due to this. 

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/composer-problem-updating

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42430658/conclusion-dont-install-laravel-framework-v4-2-22

if this doesn't work, lets arrange a kind of chat :)

Comment: Thanks you, I will try this